# Cloud Datastore returns 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

The datastore errors documentation doesn't list that this error happens. It's also not the same error that you get if you assign an individual value something too long (e.g. a blob > 1MB).

I was able to work around it by reducing the number of inserts in my batch insert, but what's the actual limit being exceeded?

Comment: Hi David, I added an answer below, and I'll work on getting this added to our documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Requests to the Cloud Datastore API are limited to 10MB.

Comment: Is there a way to check the size of a request before it goes out?

Comment: Depends on the client library. If you're using the Java protocol buffers library, you can use `getSerializedSize()`: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/javadoc/com/google/api/services/datastore/DatastoreV1.CommitRequest#getSerializedSize(). There are similar methods in other languages.